# What should i do to throw Mysql's results another js file

Tags: mysql, node.js, botkit

It's my first JS therefore it may be very novice question.
I'd like to pass sql results made by SQLQUERY.js to MAIN.js but i don't know how to handle.

SQLQUERY.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var db = require('./db/db.js');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(db);
var fs = require('fs')

connection.connect();
const sql = fs.readFileSync('./src/db/sql/selectTimeNotOnWork.sql').toString();
const sql2 = fs.readFileSync('./src/db/sql/selectTimeNotOnWorkCount.sql').toString();

var firstResult
var secondResult
connection.query(sql2,function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error; 
 firstResult = results[0].count;
 return firstResult;
});

connection.query(sql,function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error; 
 secondResult= results[0].name
 return secondResult;
});

exports ={firstResult,secondResult}
```

MAIN.JS

```
・・・・
require(./SQLQUERY.js)

controller.hears(['test'], botScope, async(bot, message) => {
    console.log(firstResult)
    console.log(secondResult)
    await bot.reply(message, firstResult);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `require()` you can either require the whole export object or use destructuring.

So in MAIN.JS you would do something like:

{firstResult, secondResult} = require('./SQLQUERY.js')

And then those two values would be available in the MAIN.js code. At least that's how I do it when I need to import specific values from the export, not the entire object. I'm not an expert either so I don't know if a simple `require('./SQLQUERY')` would make these objects available.

Comment: By the way, a probably better way to do things would be to create an object in the MYSQL.js file, and then inside this object having the methods you need. So in the MAIN.js you would write something like `const mysql = require('./MYSQL'')`, and then use this object's methods like `mysql.connect()` and `mysql.query()`, doing it this way you would have better control in MAIN.js of the errors or problems thrown by the MySql logic, it wouldn't be hidden in the other file.